# Exception in Application start method [Java FX]

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I am trying to create a button in JavaFX using Scene Builder but I am having some issues. Here is my code :

MainDesign.java

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainDesign extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = (BorderPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("application/Design.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

DesignController.java:-

```
package application;

import java.awt.Button;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;

public class DesignController {
    @FXML private Button b1;
}
```

Design.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.DesignController">
    <center>
        <Button fx:id="b1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0x22e6b9c) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0x22e6b9c
Exception running application application.MainDesign
```

[image: Error Image]

Thus , it's generating an exception in `MainDesign.java` file , I guess its regarding FXML loader.
Please help me if anyone has a solution for such issue!!!

Comment: complete stacktrace, please (__not__ as image). that said: wrong import for Button

Comment: yeah i corrected the import  method still giving same error

Comment: _same error_ which you insist in not showing

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion with the `Button` component; in **Design.fxml** you're using `javafx.scene.control.Button` and in **DesignController.java** you're using `java.awt.Button`. JavaFX and Java AWT are independant libraries, so it raises a problem when FXML loader is reading this line:

```
@FXML private Button b1;
```

because it cannot make a connection between `b1` in your FXML file and `b1` in your controller. You have to import `javafx.scene.control.Button` in your controller.